# Access to IP camera stream

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, libav

I'm trying to set up three IP cameras I got for using them in ZoneMinder.
According to the webinterface of the camera, the stream can be viewed at: `http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf`

But, since I'm writing here, this is obviously not working (at least not using `vlc` or `avconv`).

`avconv` says:

```
[http @ 0x230e9c0] HTTP error 405 Unsupported Service
http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf: Input/output error
```

`avconv -v debug` does not reveal anything new.

`vlc` says:

```
[0x7f2a680013b8] access_http access error: error: HTTP/1.0 405 Unsupported Service
[0x7f2a680013b8] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
```

However, if I access the very same address using Windows Media Player (WinXP running in VirtualBox), it works fine.

**I hope someone can shed some light on the matter and give me tips on how I can proceed.**

Edit: `vlc` do seem to be able to connect to the camera (it does find out that it is called Camera3), but is not able to play anything...

`vlc -vv http://...` says:

```
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: Creating an input for 'http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf'
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: `http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf' gives access `http' demux `' path `192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf'
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='' location='192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf' file='(null)'
[0x7fe17c0010d8] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 0 candidates
[0x7fe17c0010d8] main demux debug: no access_demux module matched "http"
[0x7fe17c0010d8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.180 ms - Total 0.180 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.180 ms)
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: creating access 'http' location='192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf', path='(null)'
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
[0x12ce1c8] qt4 interface debug: IM: Setting an input
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: asking libproxy about url 'http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf'
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: libproxy suggest to use 'direct://'
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: http: server='192.168.47.202' port=8090 file='/live.asf'
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: net: connecting to 192.168.47.202 port 8090
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: connection succeeded (socket = 13)
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: protocol 'HTTP' answer code 405
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access error: error: HTTP/1.0 405 Unsupported Service
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: switching to HTTP version 1.0
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: net: connecting to 192.168.47.202 port 8090
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: connection succeeded (socket = 13)
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access debug: protocol 'HTTP' answer code 405
[0x7fe17c001418] access_http access error: error: HTTP/1.0 405 Unsupported Service
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: net: connecting to 192.168.47.202 port 8090
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: connection succeeded (socket = 13)
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: HTTP reply 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: content-length = 627
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: stream type = broadcast
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: complete header size=615
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: packet count=0 packet size=65535
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: starting stream
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: net: connecting to 192.168.47.202 port 8090
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: connection succeeded (socket = 13)
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: HTTP reply 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Content-Type: application/vnd.ms.wms-hdr.asfv1
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Server: Cougar/9.01.01.3814
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Content-Length: 627
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Pragma: charset=UTF-8
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Date: Fri, 02 Jun 2006 08:52:23 GMT
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Pragma: no-cache, pipeline-experiment=1, client-id=517094983, xResetStrm=1, features="broadcast", timeout=60000
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, x-wms-stream-type="broadcast", user-public, must-revalidate, x-wms-proxy-split
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Jun 2006 08:52:23 GMT
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.predstrm, com.microsoft.wm.fastcache, com.microsoft.wm.startupprofile
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: using access module "access_mms"
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 10087.772 ms - Total 10087.772 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 10087.772 ms)
[0x7fe17c007428] main stream debug: Using block method for AStream*
[0x7fe17c007428] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x7fe17c007428] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0x7fe17c007428] main stream debug: prebuffering done 615 bytes in 0s - 20709 KiB/s
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates

[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 10024.180 ms - Total 10024.180 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 10024.179 ms)
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.289 ms - Total 0.289 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.289 ms)
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='' location='192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf' file='(null)'
[0x7fe17c005e08] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 54 candidates
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x75b22630-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:565
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "header object" subobj:5, reserved1:1, reserved2:2
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x8cabdca1-0xa947-0x11cf-0x8ee400c00c205365 size:104
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "file properties object" file_id:0x0-0x0-0x0-0x0000000000000000 file_size:0 creation_date:0 data_packets_count:0 play_duration:0 send_duration:0 preroll:0 flags:1 min_data_packet_size:65535  max_data_packet_size:65535 max_bitrate:500000
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x5fbf03b5-0xa92e-0x11cf-0x8ee300c00c205365 size:156
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "header extension object" reserved1:0xabd3d211-0xa9ba-0x11cf-0x8ee600c00c205365 reserved2:6 header_extension_size:110
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x14e6a5cb-0xc672-0x4332-0x8399a96952065b5a size:110
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "extended stream properties object":
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - start=0 end=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - data bitrate=500000 buffer=1000 initial fullness=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - alternate data bitrate=500000 buffer=1000 initial fullness=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - maximum object size=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - flags=0x0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - stream number=1 language=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - average time per frame=1000000
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - stream name count=0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - payload extension system count=1
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x75b22633-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:64
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "content description object" title:"Camera3" artist:"" copyright:"" description:"" rating:""
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0xb7dc0791-0xa9b7-0x11cf-0x8ee600c00c205365 size:129
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "stream Properties object" stream_type:0xbc19efc0-0x5b4d-0x11cf-0xa8fd00805f5c442b error_correction_type:0x20fb5700-0x5b55-0x11cf-0xa8fd00805f5c442b time_offset:0 type_specific_data_length:51 error_correction_data_length:0 flags:0x1 stream_number:1
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x86d15240-0x311d-0x11d0-0xa3a400a0c90348f6 size:82
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "codec list object" reserved_guid:0x86d15241-0x311d-0x11d0-0xa3a400a0c90348f6 codec_entries_count:1
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:   - codec[0] video name:"Topsee Video" description:"" information_length:4
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: found object guid: 0x75b22636-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:50
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: read "data object" file_id:0x0-0x0-0x0-0x0000000000000000 total data packet:0 reserved:257
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: + 'Unknown' GUID 0x0-0x0-0x0-0x0000000000000000 size:0pos:0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      + 'Header' GUID 0x75b22630-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:565pos:0
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    + 'File Properties' GUID 0x8cabdca1-0xa947-0x11cf-0x8ee400c00c205365 size:104pos:30
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    + 'Header Extension' GUID 0x5fbf03b5-0xa92e-0x11cf-0x8ee300c00c205365 size:156pos:134
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    |    + 'Extended Stream Properties' GUID 0x14e6a5cb-0xc672-0x4332-0x8399a96952065b5a size:110pos:180
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    + 'Content Description' GUID 0x75b22633-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:64pos:290
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    + 'Stream Properties' GUID 0xb7dc0791-0xa9b7-0x11cf-0x8ee600c00c205365 size:129pos:354
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      |    + 'Codec List' GUID 0x86d15240-0x311d-0x11d0-0xa3a400a0c90348f6 size:82pos:483
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug:      + 'Data' GUID 0x75b22636-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c size:50pos:565
[0x7fe17c005e08] asf demux debug: found 1 streams
[0x7fe17c005e08] asf demux debug: added new video stream(ID:1)
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[0x7fe17c007428] main stream warning: 0 bytes need to be skipped (access non seekable)

[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
[0x7fe17c005e08] main demux debug: using demux module "asf"
[0x7fe17c005e08] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 7.017 ms - Total 7.017 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 7.017 ms)
[0x7fe17c004018] main decoder debug: looking for decoder module: 31 candidates
[0x7fe17c004018] avcodec decoder debug: libavcodec initialized (interface 0x352300)
[0x7fe17c004018] avcodec decoder debug: trying to use direct rendering
[0x7fe17c004018] avcodec decoder debug: allowing 3 thread(s) for decoding
[0x7fe17c004018] avcodec decoder debug: ffmpeg codec (MS MPEG-4 Video v3) started
[0x7fe17c004018] main decoder debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
[0x7fe17c004018] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 19.934 ms - Total 19.934 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 19.934 ms)
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access warning: unimplemented query in control
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/derigs/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7fe17c01ebd8] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.094 ms - Total 1.094 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.094 ms)

[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: `http://192.168.47.202:8090/live.asf' successfully opened

[0x7fe17c005e08] asf demux warning: cannot peek while getting new packet, EOF ?
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: EOF reached
[0x12cb968] main playlist debug: finished input

[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: waitpipe: object killed
[0x7fe17c004018] main decoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
[0x7fe17c004018] avcodec decoder debug: ffmpeg codec (MS MPEG-4 Video v3) stopped
[0x7fe17c004018] main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `DIV3', 1 PES in FIFO
[0x7fe17c005e08] main demux debug: removing module "asf"
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x8cabdca1-0xa947-0x11cf-0x8ee400c00c205365
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x14e6a5cb-0xc672-0x4332-0x8399a96952065b5a
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x5fbf03b5-0xa92e-0x11cf-0x8ee300c00c205365
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x75b22633-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0xb7dc0791-0xa9b7-0x11cf-0x8ee600c00c205365
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x86d15240-0x311d-0x11d0-0xa3a400a0c90348f6
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x75b22630-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c
[0x7fe17c002788] asf stream debug: free asf object 0x75b22636-0x668e-0x11cf-0xa6d900aa0062ce6c
[0x7fe190000b78] main input debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
[0x7fe17c002788] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
[0x7fe17c001418] main access debug: removing module "access_mms"
[0x7fe17c001418] access_mms access debug: closing stream
[0x12cb968] main playlist debug: dead input
[0x12cb968] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[0x12cb968] main playlist debug: nothing to play
[0x12ce1c8] qt4 interface debug: IM: Deleting the input
```

Comment: What kind of camera are you using? Is there any username/password you need to supply?

Comment: I do not have to supply an username using Win Media Player, so the answer is no. The problem with the "kind of camera" is that it is not porperly branded. On the outside there is only written "EX-VIEW IP CAMERA". The Firmware version says: "3C-CNW 版本号: V1.0.87". Overall it is an outdoor IP camera with wired connection. That's all I can say about it right now.

Comment: I found it: http://www.uxcell.com/professional-color-weatherproof-exview-ccd-camera-p-51620.html